# Haskell express relationship between type values

Tags: haskell, types, entity-relationship

I am new to haskell, I started for my own "culture" to code the following project https://owickstrom.github.io/domain-modelling-with-haskell-workshop/, my first attempt was to define Budget and Project as separate data types (as suggested by the author) but rapidly when working on the function getBudget I was unable to find a way of relating a given Project with its Budget with reference to projectID field.
[ I just follow gradually the instruction and create code along the way, personally I think that budget should an "intrinsic" attribute of a project and no need to create a separate structure for coding the Budget which should lead to attempt2, but nevertheless...]

attempt1:

```
data Budget = Budget ProjectID Income Expenditure deriving Show
data Project = SingleP ProjectID Name| GroupP [Project] deriving Show
```

for testing purposes I created two "instances"

```
testProject = SingleP 1 "Haskell workshop"
testBudget = Budget 1 100000.0 50000.0
```

testProject <-> testBudget are related by the ID of the project. I didn't manage to write a function that will take an ID then "lookup" a corresponding Budget and retrieve budget data. Failing to do this, I think that I should create a data type which "embeds" the relation like this (attempt2):

```
data Budget = Budget Income Expenditure   
data Project = SingleP ProjectID Name Budget ....
```

then `testProject = SingleP 1 "Haskell worskhop" testBudget`

My questions:
- Am I right saying that it's not possible to code such relationship, (I suspect that this is due to variable immutability, simply saying I cannot "access" testBudget in Haskell)?
- any such "sql'ish" Domain Model should build around "total" Data type i.e. one that "encapsulate" also the relation, because the relation cannot be programmed in a functional way.

Comment: Well where do you store the `Budget`s? They must be in a kind of list somewhere right? You can easily write a function `lookupProject :: [Budget] -> ProjectID -> Budget`. Of course in a real life application you would just use a database.

Comment: May be my example is awkward, I also feel that "records" should exist somewhere outside the program to work this out (a list is kind of storing structure). I came to this problem when I wanted to implement the getBudget with my two test value. I think in OOP this is piece of cake. I think in FPL you do not manipulate object but structure (object inside). If my question is misplaced I have no pb if my post is banned.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not right. That function can be easily coded.

You could start e.g. with two lists, of types `[Budget]` and `[Project]`.

Then using the module `Data.Map` you could build two dictionaries, `Map ProjectID Budget` and `Map ProjectId Project`, and run your lookup queries on those. These would serve as two database tables.

If budgets and projects tables exist separately, you can pair up different budgets and projects tables as arguments to your query functions.

If you push the budget into your project data type, you'd have just one table, which could also be implemented as a `Map` of course. Then if a project's budget changes you'd have to update that table, i.e. create its copy with an updated entry for that project. This is also easily done with the functions from same `Data.Map` module.